# Pop up will display after removing cookies

Tags: magento-1.9, cookie, browser

We have custom button "**Save design**" in [product view page](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html) , once guest user clicked on that, it will display **pop up** as below, but after sometime, onclick button will not display pop up  box, but once we delete **cookies** from browser, than pop up will display again.

In Private window also pop up will display initially, after some time same issue.

```
    <button onclick="return setproductlogin(\'<?php echo  
    Mage::registry("current_product")->getId()?>\', event);setrequestlogin();"  
     id="submit-editorApply-{{rand}}" >SAVE DESIGN</button>
```

**script**

```
function setproductlogin(pid, event)
{
event.preventDefault();
document.getElementById("likeproduct_id").value=pid;
jQuery("#productlistlogin").trigger("click");
return false;
}
```

[image]

Browser cookies

[image]

**Edit**

when I delete **var/session** folder also issue is still there, pop up will work only after removing cookies from Browser

Comment: Do you get a JavaScript error when clicking the button? Or do you see any broken requests (when using Ajax to load the block)?

Comment: @ArjenMiedema There is no js console errors in [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html)

Comment: I do see one error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'change' of null`. But in my case, the form always shows up.

Comment: @ArjenMiedema yes, seems that error is not related to that, as pop up is working after we clear cookies, also it works fine in fresh browsers, after sometimes, same issue will happen in your system also....

Comment: I clicked multiple time it show popup

Comment: you have two frontend cookies. most likely because of hitting both non-www and www domain while no fixed cookie domain is set. this may cause session issues

Answer (score 0):

try to set a fixed cookie domain for this store, remove cookies and test this Issue again.